# ¿Cómo obtener el ID de faccebook desde android studio?

Tags: java, android-studio, api, facebook, android-intent

quisiera saber si existe alguna libreria en android studio o alguna clases que con el usuario de facebook, pudiera obtener el id, para asi abrir desde la aplicacion su perfil -Si se encuentra instalada-, es que estoy desarrollando la aplicacion donde el cliente solo escribe su usuario de facebook pero quiero redirigirlo a su perfil de facebook con dicho usuario, quisiera obtener su id para poder abrirlo, bien sea desde la aplicacion o si la app de facebook no se encuentra instalada ya con el usuario digitado lo haria desde el navegador. Gracias.

Comment: Saludos compañero, te invito a pasarte por la pagina de facebook developer y mirar las diferentes guias para hacer un sign in con facebook.

saludos y buena energia.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/

Comment: @JulianCuevas Gracias amigo, pero en mi aplicación no realizo un logueo con facebook, ni nada por el estilo, solo el cliente "registra su usuario de facebook" un string simple y con ese string quisiera obtener el id del facebook. Gracias igual por el comentario. !